# E-mails are being truncated by Gmail or Yahoo

Tags: email

When I send an e-mail to a user, most of the times Yahoo user, and Yahoo returns a bounce to my Gmail account, that bounces comes most of the time truncated.

What's my problem here? Is in Gmail that truncates the messages, if yes, how do I fix it, or it is because of Yahoo?

thanks!

It shows like this in the bounce:

-

```
-- Original message follows.

The original message is over 5K. Message truncated.\
```

Is Yahoo who does this?

Comment: Can you explain how exactly the bounce message is truncated?

Comment: I've edited the question and added that info. Thanks

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The reason that the message is truncated is because the server (in this case Yahoo's) doesn't see the point in sending back the whole message in a bounce message. The theory is that you have the whole message already if you sent it! It just gives you enough back so you can work out which message has bounced.

If the address had existed then the message would not have been truncated and would be received in full by the recipient.

Comment: Yes but that way, if I want to receive the bounce in another e-mail account, I have no information about the original message.

Comment: That's true. I think the method of handling this is to put some form of identifier within the first 5k and use that to correlate in your backend system. Either that or the combination of date/time and destination email address.

Comment: The method of handling this, for people who want to associate bounce messages with accounts being sent to, has been around since at least 1997.  It is _Variable Envelope Return Paths_.  There's no need for even that 5KiB with VERPs.

Answer (score -3):

I have found a quick fix to this truncation problem. The message is truncated upon printout.
 1. Display the gmail message.
 2. On the upper right, click on the firefox symbol.
 3. From the new window, click on the print symbol.
 4. From the upper left "scale", choose 40%(50% gives truncation).
 5. From the upper left, "print".

Dick McMullen

Comment: No, it's not. This is not what the OP is asking about.